# If I wanted to create my resume in Illustrator/Sketch what pixel dimensions should I use?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, resume, sketch-app

If I create a 8.5x11in file in Photoshop, it works out to 612x792. If I want to create a resume in Illustrator or another program like Sketch by Bohemian Coding should I use that size? Or would it be wiser to use a different one (such as a doubled version of that)?

Comment: Will this resume be printed out? Illustrator doesn't really care about pixels. If this resume is to be printed out, why not specify the document size in inches?

Comment: I'm creating it in Sketch by Bohemian Coding, and it doesn't support inches.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the proportions are correct and you're not using raster elements, it shouldn't really matter what your pixel size is in terms of getting a quality print. Vector elements are pixel-independent.

Without actually getting in and trying it, I'd suggest keeping 612x792 though, because it'll give you more predictable results when it comes to using fonts at certain sizes. If you double the size, your 10pt text will probably become 20pt text.